# Java + Selenium Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()

Tags: java, selenium

I am having issues trying to run Selenium Web driver in a specific way, I've have setup TestNG + Selenium Web driver in my framework, the thing that I would like to accomplish is to run two suites that I've set up in the TestNG.xml files as bellow:

**TestNG.xml**

```
<suite>
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="src/testNG/suites/UserSignsOn.xml" />
        <suite-file path="src/testNG/suites/PreSetup.xml" />
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

**PreSetup.xml**

```
<suite name="Pre Setup">
    <test name="pre setup suite">
        <classes>
            <class name="Tests.PreSetup" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**UserSignsOn.xml**

```
<suite name="User Signs On">
    <test name="Get the Web Application">
        <classes>
            <class name="Tests.LoginPageTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

My test files look like this:

**LoginPageTest.class**

```
public class LoginPageTest extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    @Description("Login to the web application")
    public void signInTheWebApplicationLocalHost(){ // some steps here }
}
```

**PreSetup.class**

```
public class PreSetup extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    @Description("Pre setup")
    public void preSetupSteps(){ // some steps here }
}
```

As you can see my Test files extends a class, which is the following:

**BaseTest.class**

```
public class BaseTest {

    protected EnvironmentManager environmentManager;

    @BeforeTest
    public void testSetup() {
        environmentManager = EnvironmentManager.getInstance();

        if(environmentManager.getDriver() == null){
            // Here I am set up the driver!!!
            environmentManager.initWebdriver();
            environmentManager.startWebApplication();
        }
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void testName(ITestResult result){ // perform some actions }

    @AfterMethod
    public void status(ITestResult result){ // perform some actions }

    @AfterTest // Here I am shutting down the driver
    public void tearDown() { environmentManager.shutdownDriver(); }
}
```

The **BaseTest.class** calls to the **EnvironmentManager.class** which is a singleton class

It has the bellow code:

```
public class EnvironmentManager {

    private static EnvironmentManager instance = null;
    private WebDriver driver = null;
    private String url = "www.google.com";

    private EnvironmentManager(){}


    // Public Methods
    public void initWebdriver() {
        if(driver == null){ driver = new ChromeDriver(); }
    }

    public void startWebApplication(){ driver.get(url); }

    // Singleton method
    public static EnvironmentManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) instance = new EnvironmentManager();
        return instance;
    }

    public void shutdownDriver(){
        driver.quit();
        driver = null;
    }


    public WebDriver getDriver(){ return driver; }
}
```

The issue resides after running the second test "PreSetup", in the console I got the error:

```
Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
```

I notice that in the first test the driver session is:

```
ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (0ff799fbfd14fc275b3b45c414765b15)
```

And in the second test is a different one:

```
ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (09c6c47344756fe2979ee8a84094b1e3)
```

Any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

for all interested the solution is to rename the following testNG annotations:

@BeforeTest
@AfterTest

to

@BeforeSuite
@AfterSuite